# Float span right in table using spans as columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

Because of some [nuances with jQuery's Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772569/use-jquery-sortable-with-hidden-table-rows-in-django-template), I'm displaying a table element in HTML, but using 's to create the columns instead of 's (below and in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/1/)):

```
<style>        
  /* Title row for an action/item */
  .item-row {
    display: table-row;
  }

  /* Keep icon columns narrow */
  .icon_column { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
  }

  /* Item columns that are not icons */
  .name_column {
    display: table-cell;
  }    

  .extra_column {
    display: table-cell;
    float: right;
  }
</style>
<table class='table table-condensed'>
  <thead>
    <tr class='table_header'>
      <th>
        <div class='item-row'>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='name_column'>Name</span>
          <span class='extra_column'>Date</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='item_row'>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='name_column'>Name 1</span>
          <span class='extra_column'>Date 1</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='item_row'>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='name_column'>Row 2 Name 2</span>
          <span class='extra_column'>Date 2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='item_row'>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
          <span class='name_column'>Name 3</span>
          <span class='extra_column'>Date 3</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want each item-row to display as one line with the extra_column floating all the way to the right.  The extra_column seems to be to the right, but the entire item-row seems to be defaulting to two lines.

How can I correct this CSS?
​

Comment: by 'floating all the way to the right', do you mean what Luis proposed? It is (text) aligned to the right. Should it also actually look as a table? In other words, should each last 'cell' in a row be aligned with eachother?

Comment: sorry, the item-row vs item_row bit was my oversight in this code only

Comment: @TweeZz, yes I would want it lined up like an actual table.  The last cells should be aligned with each other vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/8/) what you are looking for?

I basically wrapped 2 groups of spans each in another span.. the first group gets float:left and the second group float:right.

CSS:

```
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='item-row'>
  <span class='left'>
    <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
    <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
    <span class='icon_column'>*</span>
    <span class='name_column'>Name</span>
  </span>
  <span class='right'>
    <span class='extra_column'>Date</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I must add that when the content of 1 row extends the space (width) it gets, this goes wrong. I am not sure how thát could be achieved :)

**[UPDATE]**
By [giving the name_column a fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/10/) (like 150px), you can get rid of the issue mentioned above. It still goes wrong when the last column has too much data. That probably could be solved by also giving that a fixed width.
You can get rid of the div wrapper ('table_container') if you want it to span 'the page'.

Comment: Interesting solution.  Is it possible to make the item-row the full width of the screen without hardcoding the width of the name_column?

Comment: This is the closest to the functionality I want.  I'm probably going to use another div on the name_column with an overflow: hidden to just cut off text that goes too long.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/2/

**CSS markup:**

```
.extra_column {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right; /*use this instead*/
    /*float: right;*/ /*this was the problem*/
  }
```

As you can see in [this last example](http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/3/), it is aligned to the right.

---

**UPDATED**

This should be a good solution at what you're asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/QgpRY/12/

```
  /* Keep icon columns narrow */
  .icon_column { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px !important;
  }

  /* Item columns that are not icons */
  .name_column {
    display: table-cell;
    width:81% !important;
  }    

  .extra_column {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50px !important;
  }
```

It would be a lot easier if you can change all to `<div>`'s

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is good, but I want each item-row to be the same width and the extra_column to be aligned with the other extra_columns vertically.

Comment: Ok, we might be getting close.  A few comments: I want the icon_columns to be 20px wide.  The extra_column should be 50px let's say.  And the entire item-row should be 100% of the width of the area/screen. Is this possible?

Comment: This is good, but hard-coding 81% still leaves room for unneeded space to the right if the page is sufficiently wide